# "DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found" on discord.js v12.5.3 when trying to delete slash commands CLOSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm remaking a discord.js music bot I made a while back and I made a mistake and want to delete my slash commands so I can redo them. But when I do the client.api.application(client.user.id).guilds(<GUILD_ID>).commands(<COMMAND_ID>).delete() method it gves me this error:

```
DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\bot.js:69:5 {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/applications/862703509191262228/guilds/836619732530102332/commands/882295078486425640/commands/882295078931017809/commands/882295079807647755',
  code: 0,
  httpStatus: 404
}
```

My code is:

```
async function getCommands(guild) {
    return client.api
        .applications(client.user.id)
        .guilds(guild.id)
        .commands.get();
}

const guildCommands = client.api
            .applications(client.user.id)
            .guilds(guild.id);

let slashCommands = await getCommands(guild).catch(console.error);
            slashCommands.forEach(async (slashCommand) => {
                await guildCommands.commands(slashCommand.id).delete();
            });
```

Comment: Try removing `.commands(slashCommand.id)` and just running `slashCommand.delete()` tell me what happens.

Comment: @MrMythical hi again! I get this error:
```
TypeError: slashCommands.delete is not a function
    at C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\bot.js:69:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\bot.js:68:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Currently the path is `/applications/862703509191262228/guilds/836619732530102332/commands/882295078486425640/commands/882295078931017809/commands/882295079807647755` but it should be `/applications/862703509191262228/guilds/836619732530102332/commands/882295078486425640 `. There must be a mistake somewhere in GETTING the commands.

Comment: @MrMythical Ok I'm gonna look

Comment: @MrMythical I was unable to find anything wrong.

Comment: @MrMythical Solved it! I don't really know what I did. I changed the way you got the commands and that worked. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I also put an answer. You can mark it as correct if you want.

Comment: You should not just edit in the word "CLOSED" to your question. You can delete it if you don’t want it to be on the site anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly getting the commands. Currently the path is

> /applications/862703509191262228/guilds/836619732530102332/commands/882295078486425640/commands/882295078931017809/commands/882295079807647755

But you want it to be

> /applications/862703509191262228/guilds/836619732530102332/commands/882295078486425640

Make sure the way you get the commands is correct. You are trying to access the nonexistent 'commands' property of a command.